# Parentheses for quantifiers in First-Order Logic affect logical operators normally?

Tags: first-order-logic, predicate-logic, quantifiers

I'm sure this is a very simple question, but I cannot manage to find it explictly answered anywhere. **Do parentheses used for quantifiers also affect logical operators normally?**

For example, if parentheses affect logical operators normally, the following formula:

$\forall x(P(x) \land \exists y(Q(y) \rightarrow R(x,y)))$

Would be equivalent, in terms of its structure, to:

$P \land (Q \rightarrow R)$

Whereas this one:

$\forall x(P(x) \land \exists y(Q(y)) \rightarrow R(x,y))$

Would be equivalent to:

$P \land Q \rightarrow R \equiv (P \land Q) \rightarrow R$

If it turns out that parentheses used for quantifiers do not affect the preference of "non-quantifier" logical operators, then both cases would be the same... **So could someone please confirm whether I am right, and parentheses used for quantifiers affect all logical operators normally?**

Thanks in advance for your time! :)

Comment: $\forall x(P(x) \land \exists y(Q(y)) \rightarrow R(x,y))$  Has unmatched parenthesis, and so is ambiguous.

Comment: Can you say what " parentheses affect logical operators normally," means?

Comment: The formula shouldn't have unmatched parentheses: the outer ones embrace the whole formula from $\forall x$ onwards, and, aside from the parentheses for each predicate, the $\exists y$ has parentheses only surrounding the Q predicate.

Comment: By that I mean whether they modify the priority of operators: meaning that $P \land Q \rightarrow R$ would be equivalent to $(P \land Q) \rightarrow R$, because $\land$ has priority over $\rightarrow$, but $P \land (Q \rightarrow R)$ would not be equivalent to the previous formula, as the explicit parentheses would modify the "normal" priority of $\land$ over $\rightarrow$.

Comment: Yes, parenthesis used for quantifiers affect all logical operators normally.

Comment: Thanks! Could you add this as an answer so I can mark it as solved?